# How can I restrict user defined attribute application in D?

Tags: d, introspection

I want to make a user defined attribute attachable only to the struct/class methods. In Java's annotation there is such option: @Target restricts annotation attach targets. Is there analogue in D?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you could make the processor you write that handles it `static assert(0)` if it finds it attached to one.